# Show, by the element method that, for all subsets P, Q, and R of U, (P − Q) ∩ (R − Q) = (P ∩ R) − Q.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

i do not seem to what element method is. Please explain me how to use the element method

Comment: Take am element in the set on the LHS and show it is a member of the set of the RHS. This shows one containment. Then do the same for the reverse containment.

Comment: (1) Please don't put your question in the title, the body should be self contained. (2) Your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: ) If x ∈ (P − Q) ∩ (R − Q) then x is in P but not in
Q AND x is in R but not in Q.) Thus x is in P and R, but x is not in Q.
 Thus x is in (P ∩R)−Q. This shows that (P −Q)∩(R−Q) ⊆ (P ∩R)−Q

Comment: what to do after that

Comment: Draw a picture. Venn diagrams is your friend. Clarification: This type of problem, can easily be proved using [Venn diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram). Even an elementary picture, can be considered as a proof. In this case, draw 3 circles, as on the wikipedia page, and identify left hand side, and right hand side in the picture. Note that the regions for both "interpretations" are the same.

Answer (score 1):

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\notag \\ #1 \quad & \quad \text{"#2"} \notag \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\notag \end{align}}
$The element method, also known as element chasing, is about proving two sets $\;A\;$ and $\;B\;$ equal by proving they have exactly the same element, i.e., proving that -- for any $\;x\;$ -- if $\;x \in A\;$ then also $\;x \in B\;$, and vice versa.  Very often this just comes down to expanding the definitions and simplifying.

In this specific case, the simplest thing is to start at the most complex side, so $\;(P - Q) \cap (R - Q)\;$, and calculate which $\;x\;$ this set contains:
$$\calc
x \in (P - Q) \cap (R - Q)
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;\cap\;$}
x \in P - Q \;\land\; x \in R - Q
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;-\;$, twice}
(x \in P \land x \not\in Q) \;\land\; (x \in R \land x \not\in Q)
\calcop{\equiv}{logic: simplify by factoring out the common conjunct $\;x \not\in Q\;$}
\ldots
\endcalc$$

Answer (score 0):

Element method is
Assume x as an element of p-q intersection r-q now prove that the same x is an element of p intersection r minus q.

For each x this should be applicable.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial :)](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)